# why Recyclerview.Viewholder deprecated?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, deprecated

Today, suddenly `Recyclerview.Viewholder` became deprecated. Other, android project is no deprecated.

How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: What version of the `recyclerview-v7` dependency are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to extend the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class, just keep it a POJO.